# how can i Fetching Data and Updating State with Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i have a var `resourcesData` with 5 empty arrays and 3 arrays with objects of data i'm not sure how can i pass that 3 arrays with object of data into useState and manage it

```
  const resourcesData = data;
```

[image: Console.log(resourcesData)]

i try something like this

```
  const [datos, setDatos] = React.useState(resourcesData);
```

but if i log `datos` it return me only empty arrays with no the 3 arrays with objects of data so do you know what i'm doing wrong or how can i manage the state of that 3 arrays with objects ?

[image: Console.log(datos)]

Comment: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/managing-state

Comment: that doesn't help with my problem

Comment: Hi, can you give me sample data of resourcesData? in console.log the structure is not pretty clear.

Comment: please add more detail to your question. share all code on your component

Comment: i'm trying to store my data and manage it with useState but the problem is the data is not already load so is the reason why it returning empty arrays

Answer (score 0):

By the time you are calling this statement `const [datos, setDatos] = React.useState(resourcesData);` data has not been loaded that's why you are getting empty array.

So for that purpose you can use a useEffect, like this:

```js
const [datos, setDatos] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect (()=>{
setDatos(resourcesData);
// if you want to get only the non empty arrays
// you can do it like this:
const FilteredData = resourcesData.filter((arr) => arr.length > 0);
setDatos(resourcesData);
},[resourcesData]);
```

Comment: you should either rename `data` to `resourcesData` or remove it as dependency